# execution sql command

Tags: php

what the factor that the code not work?

```
<?php
class mysql
{
    var $user;
    var $password;
    var $database;
    var $host;
    var $out;
    var $query;

    function mysql($username, $password, $database, $host, $query)
    {
        $this->user = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->query = $query;
    }
    function connect()
    {
        $this->out = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password)
                or die("Error cannnot connect to mysql server");
                echo "Connected successfully to Mysql server";
        mysql_select_db($this->database) or die("Cannot select db");

    }
    function execution()
    {
        $re = mysql_query($this->query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($re))
            echo $row;
    }
    function out()
    {
        mysql_close($this->out);
    }

}
$connect = new mysql('root','','test','127.0.0.1');
$connect->connect();
$connect->execution('test','SELECT * FROM test');
$connect->out;


?>
```

**Update**

```
$connect = new mysql('root','','test','127.0.0.1','SELECT ss from test');
```

I have trying above code and its dont return nothing..

ss contain an column name ID and its contain the 11 value.

Comment: Please just edit your question to provide additional information. Additionally, you can use the comment feature under any answer on any question that you've asked. Please take some time to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a couple of your function calls are passing the incorrect amount of parameters. Your mysql() constructor should take 5 but you're only giving it 4. Also, execution() doesn't take any and you're trying to give it 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor should be `new mysql('root','','test','127.0.0.1', 'SELECT * FROM test');`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `$query` parameter in your `mysql()` call:

```
$connect = new mysql('root','','test','127.0.0.1');
```

should be

```
$connect = new mysql('root','','test','127.0.0.1', 'SELECT * FROM test');
```

Although moving the parameter for the `$query` to the `execution()` method is cleaner.